# If $B$ is a subset of a Banach space is it true that if $\operatorname{span} B$ is closed then $\operatorname{span} B$ is finite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a separable Banach space

Let $B \subset V$ be a linearly independent, closed and bounded subset of $V$

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\operatorname{span} B
\text{ is closed }
\Longrightarrow 
\operatorname{span} B
\text
{ is finite dimensional}
$$

thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question because if you drop any of the assumptions "$B$ is linearly independent", "$B$ is closed", or "span $B$ is closed", it becomes false.

Comment: thanks @NateEldredge

Comment: thanks @NateEldredge i edit to add that it's separable because it's in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the claim is true.

There are some nice results in the paper

> *Bartoszyński, Tomek; Džamonja, Mirna; Halbeisen, Lorenz; Murtinová, Eva; Plichko, Anatolij*, [**On bases in Banach spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm170-2-3), Stud. Math. 170, No. 2, 147-171 (2005). [ZBL1093.46012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1093.46012).

Let's let $W = \operatorname{span} B$; note that $W$ is also separable.  Suppose $B$ is linearly independent and $W$ is closed and infinite dimensional; then $B$ is a Hamel basis for $W$.  Note that $B$ is closed in $W$ iff it is closed in $V$.  It is shown in Theorem 3.10 of the above paper that a Hamel basis for an infinite-dimensional separable Banach cannot be an analytic set, and in particular it cannot be closed.

(There should be a much more elementary argument to just show directly that it can't be closed.  I will think about it.)

If you don't assume $V$ is separable then it can fail.  Theorem 3.8 of the above paper shows that for sufficiently large Hilbert spaces ($V = \ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ would do), it is possible to construct a Hamel basis which is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your interest on the question i asked... very kindly